# Material design lite and small screens

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm having some trouble with material design lite.  I've made a page that looks great on a computer, but its not responsive at all.  I'm using example code copied directly from the getmdl.io components page...and on that page everything looks great on a phone, but on my page it looks like a desktop only site (really small, hard to read).  Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Solved this by adding
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> between the <head> tags.

Comment: It is not working for me... I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, i solved it in this form:

My Code Navbar Header of MDL:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
```

Try with this form:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
```

Greetz.